# Extending `Error` results in "only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here"

Tags: typescript

I have Typescript 4.0.2. In lib.es5.d.ts, there is the following fragment:

```
interface Error {
    name: string;
    message: string;
    stack?: string;
}

interface ErrorConstructor {
    new(message?: string): Error;
    (message?: string): Error;
    readonly prototype: Error;
}

declare var Error: ErrorConstructor;
```

I am able to use `const err = new Error("some message");`

I want to extend `Error` to add a property named `statusCode` to handle Http errors. I tried:

```
interface HttpException extends Error {
  // new(message?: string): Error;
  // (message?: string): HttpException;
  // readonly prototype: HttpException;
  statusCode?: number
}
```

But I am not able to use `const e = new HttpException("Not found");`. The error is `'HttpError' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here. (ts2693)`

Why can't `HttpException` be used in a similar manner to `Error`?

Comment: Because `HttpException` is only an interface. `Error` is a concrete object. `declare var Error: ErrorConstructor;` makes sure TS knows that.

Comment: Btw, you can use any class as a type, but you can't use any type as a class

Comment: @VLAZ Why is `Error` a concrete object? What do the three lines in `ErrorConstructor` mean?

Comment: @OldGeezer it's a concrete object because it has an implementation and thus you can call `new` with it. `HttpException` is just an interface, it defines the public API of an object but supplies no implementation for them. That's also what the three lines in `ErrorConstructor` define - the public interface. In that case, it says that you can call it with `new` (which takes an optional parameter), or call it as a function without `new` (also takes an optional parameter), finally there is a `prototype` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lib.es5.d.ts` describes existing APIs (`Error` constructor in this case), but you're defining completely new one. Types/interfaces are erased at compile time hence the error. `new` keyword requires class or function that specifies the type of the object instance.

```
class HttpException extends Error {
    statusCode?: number
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEASAu8AOBRAHsApk+BLA9gHbSZryaEAmMKATrfrdAN4BQ0H0E8Y8ArhADC+SpgD8ALmiE+AWwBGmWqwC+rVoUwB3OIlQZseIgAoAlBu27k6LDgKFjAcgBm+fI-NA)